# Summing up values from one column into one row on a different table when joining

Tags: sql-server, join, sum, sql-server-2017

I've only had a (frustrating) couple days experience with SQL Server, and I need some help, since I cant find anything related to my question when searching.

For background info, I'm working in an accountancy, and right now I'm trying to create a table for balance statements to use in crystal reports. Each invoice has multiple items, but for the statement I need to sum them all up with the invoice reference being the information that links the group of data that needs to be summarised.

So, what I need is to pull information from one table (dbo.SalesInvItems), this information including the date (InvDate), the due date (InvDueDate), and the customer name (CustomerName). This information stays the same with the Invoice Reference (InvRef), and it's what I want to use to link the two tables.
 *For example, Invoice Reference: 1478 will always have the date 14/05/18, the due date: 14/06/18 and the customer name: Pen Sellers Ltd.*

The same Invoice Reference is used by multiple rows, but the only thing that changes (that I need) is the Invoice Item Total (InvItemTotal).
 *For example, the one reference will always be addressed to Pen Sellers, but one item has the Total as £13 and another item using the same reference is £20.*

The Invoice Item Total is what I need to sum up. I want to add all the Invoice Item Total's together that have the same Invoice Reference, while joining the tables.

[Sales Invoices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5JYm.png)

So when I've inserted the references into the table (sorry they're not the same in both pictures, I was having problems making examples and I made a mistake), I want to grab the information from the Invoice table to fill it in, going from this...

[Pre Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVIef.png)

To this...

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpRTO.png)

The desired location is a table called dbo.Statement.

1.Is this even possible to do?
2.How would I go about doing this?
3.Is there a method I could use that would make sure that every time I insert an Invoice Reference into the Statement table, it would automatically pull out the data needed from the Invoice Table?

If any additional information is needed, just say and I'll do my best to provide it, I have never asked a question on here before and I'm new to SQL Server and coding in general.

Im using SQL Server Management Tool 2017

Thank You

Comment: What would _really_ help your question would be to rephrase it by showing sample data and the expected output.  Then, talk around that data to explain the question.

Comment: You need to provide some sample data and expected result for anyone to be able to help. Seems like you need detailed information along with aggregated data and this is usually achieved by using sub-selects or window functions in SQL Server.

Comment: I don't think you need a new table. Simply write a query joining the two tables together. And in Crystal Reports add a group by to invoice header and total Items.

Comment: Actually, I dont think you even want the details, just the aggregate of Items by Invoice. Same concept but the query is Select hdr.Invoice, Sum(item.Cost) from InvRef hdr join SalesInvItems item on hdr.InvoiceID = item.InvoiceID group by hdr.InvoiceID

Comment: You have a reference that you didn't provide a table for which is payments.

Comment: Sorry, the columns that aren't mentioned are supposed to be filled in seperately, just ignore them.

Comment: Also, the query you provided hasn't worked, I'll list the errors. 1. Multi-part identifier hdr.Invoice could not be bound 2. Invalid column name 'Cost' 3. Invalid Object Name 'InvRef' 4. Multipart definer hdr.InvoiceID could not be bound 5. InvoiceID is an invalid column 6. A repeat of no.4

Comment: I gave you that before you posted the tables to be used as a reference.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think payments was relevant because I would be putting them in manually and not drawing it from other tables.

Comment: Learn how to ask a simple, concise, useful question.  No one is going to read an essay.  Here's a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I was giving the details that I thought were necessary, I called the part that was not necessary to read was background information, and I was as concise as possible with the information needed.

Comment: I'll leave my answer as is. Adding payments later is not the best way. You should review why left join was used in my solution vs yours.

Comment: That's fair, but even so I didn't work. Anyway, there's been additions to the database, including a table that has all the information for payments, with all the information needed (more than just payments). It's a lot more complicated now and it's moved past the question. I'll make your answer main since you definitely know better though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select item.InvRef
   , item.CustomerName
   , item.InvDate
   , item.InvDueDate
   , Sum(item.InvItemTotal) InvAmt
   , sum(IsNull(payments.Amount,0)) PayAmount
   , Sum(item.InvItemTotal) InvAmt - sum(IsNull(payments.Amount,0))  as Balance
from SalesInvItems item 
left join payments -- you didn't define this
    on item.InvRef = payments.InvRef
group by item.InvRef
   , item.CustomerName
   , item.InvDate
   , item.InvDueDate
```

Comment: The payments part is causing problems, its not an important thing, it's just something to be put in individually. Also, it should be noted that the balance is already being used in a formula with the InvItemTotal and the payments. I(nvItemTotal-Payments=Balance)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I managed to figure things out taking out the payments.

Comment: Hey Keith, if you want to edit your answer and change it to the one that worked, since you helped out a lot, feel free to copy paste mine and I'll accept it as main answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select item.InvRef
   , item.CustomerName
   , item.InvDate
   , item.InvDueDate
   , Sum(item.InvItemTotal) InvAmt
from SalesInvItems item 
left join Statement
   on item.InvRef = Statement.Reference
group by item.InvRef
   , item.CustomerName
   , item.InvDate
   , item.InvDueDate
```

Comment: I haven't, his solution didn't work and this one did. It's an altered version because I took out all the payment stuff which was causing the issues. I also changed what it was joining too, because the payment information was irrelevant to the question I asked.

Comment: No one wants to know/care about the little detail.  KeithL's answer probably get you 85% of what you want, so you should accept his answer instead of posting your own answer.

Comment: But it didn't work? I'd say the parts that made it not work is more than just the 'little details'. I'm not looking for 85% the way there, I'm looking for the solution that works. I said before he made his solution to ignore the 'Payments', but he didn't, and he used it in the most important part of the solution, and other parts. If someone in my situation were to follow his answer, they would get confused because he included something I said not to include and causes errors, so it's harder for them to work out.  If he cares about getting the main answer he can make the changes.